# file writing failed sporadically with antivirus or backup program from windows

Tags: windows, file, backup, antivirus

we have java code creating, writing and deleting new files to the disk on windows, but the file operation failed sporadically;

sometimes files are created/deleted with a delay, sometimes it just failed

I suspect the antivirus or backup program caused this, and it happens more often with AVG, Symantec or Carbonite installed

anyone else runs into this problem as well?

any suggestions to work with those antivirus or backup program?

Answer (score 0):

I am a technology consultant for Symantec. And I have a lot of customers who are using java code for creating applications. If you add exceptions for the application and path to Symantec AV, you will be able to work hassle-free.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had and figured out a similar mystery related to Carbonite. I believe it can be resolved by refining your backup configuration to eliminate the folders to which your app needs to write output. Much like what @Matthew suggested for Symantic.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177753/165164