# Tiny CLion projects slow to build a second time

Tags: backup, clion, backup-strategies

I'm a Community College instructor grading student C++ coding assignments. Been doing the same task all semester. Suddenly, this morning, CLion is building extremely slowly, perhaps even hanging, the **second time** I build/run a project. WTF? The projects are very small. One source file, one header, no libraries.

What changed? And why would a second build be the problem? It's usually first builds that are slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What changed? **My harddrive backup software.** I told my auto-backup to take 2 hours off and have had no problem since.

I was recently forced to switch from the Code42 CrashPlan software I've been using for years to Carbonite. Code42 is getting out of the end-user backup business.

Note that I believe this problem is at least 95% user error, in how I configured my backup, and max 5% anything to do with Carbonite's implementation. Maybe their file locking strategy is different from CrashPlan's; I don't know.

I did think twice before I configured my CLion Projects folder to be backed up. I knew that backing up object files would be a waste of backup cycles/space. But I was in a hurry and wanted my solution source code to get backed up by Carbonite until I can check it into a repository of some sort at the end of the semester. I'm pretty sure I can go in and refine my backup strategy to NOT include the object/executable folders.